# Scheme altering tree values

Tags: tree, scheme, negate

I receive a tree and suppose to output the same tree with the values negated: 1 becomes -1, -2 becomes 2, #t becomes #f and the opposite way.

The tree is flexible - each can have multiple sons, one or none.
I'm not allowed to add user-defined helper procedures. 
However, I can use built-in (primitive) procedures: length, equal?, append, foldl, map, boolean?, not, take, last.

What I have so far is:

```
(define inverse-tree
  (lambda (tree)
    (cond ((eq? '() tree) '())
        ((pair? tree) 
         (make-tree (inverse-tree (car tree))
                    (inverse-tree (cdr tree))))
        (else (tree)))))
```

Comment: Start by identifying where this code is returning a value as opposed to a sub-tree; then it should be easy.

Comment: Instead of making a new question you should edit and add to your original one.